# css working different with react than with simple html

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to build flip cards with react but they're acting a little different than they would when used with just html

I thought It was some trouble with code but then I copied from the tutorials themselves and the code works fine with simple html file but when I put html code in react component and import the css, on flipping the card the back side size increases.

Problem: On flipping the card, the back size increases with react but works fine with html

here is the code :

index.js (css file empty)

```
  ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Flip />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

here is the flip component code (flip.js)

```
function Flip() {
return (
  <div className="flip3D">
   <div className="back">Box 1 - Back</div>
   <div className="front">Box 1 - Front</div>
  </div>
) }
```

here is the css code:

```
.flip3D{ width:240px; height:200px; margin:10px; float:left; }
 .flip3D > .front{
     position:absolute;
     -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
     transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
     background:#FC0; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px;
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
     transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
     transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 }
 .flip3D > .back{
     position:absolute;
     -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
     transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
     background: #80BFFF; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px;
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
     transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
     transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 }
 .flip3D:hover > .front{
     -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
     transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
 }
 .flip3D:hover > .back{
     -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
     transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
 }
```

These are the only files in my project so no other css file or component is conflicting with this
index.css file is empty

Expected behaviour : When this code is used in React, after flipping the size of div should remain same as it was when the front part showed

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I wasn't only importing the Flip.js in index, after deleting other components from the folder, it started working properly